# React and Ag-Grid: populating selectcelleditor through fetch gives 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using AG-Grid to build an react application to display data from an api like a spreadsheet. Getting the data and showing it works fine, know I want to edit the data, or change the value with a predefined list, which is also fetched through an api.

This is where I'm stuck since yesterday and I can't figure it out. Here is some example code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

class AgGridExample extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          rowData: [],
          selectData: []
      };
  }

   columnDefs = [
    {
        headerName: "MyListData", field: "item", editable: true, cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor",
        cellEditorParams: function () { // cellEditorParams: {values: ["1", "2"]}
            return {
                values: this.state.selectData
            }
        }
    },
    { headerName: "value", field: "value", editable: true },
];

/**
 * fetch all necessary data from data sources
 */
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/rowdata')
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(rowData => this.setState({ rowData }))

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/selectdata')
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(selectData => this.setState({ selectData }))
};

render() {
    return (
        <AgGridReact
            enableSorting={true}
            enableFilter={true}
            rowData={this.state.rowData}
            columnDefs={this.columnDefs}>
        </AgGridReact>
    );
};
}


export default AgGridExample;
```

The Data:

> rowData: [{"value": "a", "item":"1"}, {"value": "b", "item":"2"}]
>
> selectData: ["1", "2"]

Now I'm new with react and as far as I understood, the best place to fetch the data from an external source is in *componentDidMount* and updating the state. I did some reading, and the problem seems to be, that  it is rendered, before the data is fetched, or the state could be updated. I tried with *componentWillMount*, but I got the same error, when I try to edit the field:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

What would be the best practice to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help, hints, examples.

Comment: Here is a link for How to fetch data in React
https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data/

You should use componentDidMount to fetch data. And it's ok that the component is render before the data is fetched, you just need to define the state with initialised values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I'm doing everything correctly? When you look into the code, I'm fetching the data by using componentDidMount, but when I want to use it in `values: this.state.selectData` I get an TypeError. I don't want to initialize the state hardcoded with all the values, because they are provided through an api. That's why it's initialized empty.

Comment: reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily. Go through [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems more like a Javascript problem than anything to do with ag-grid.
The `this` inside return object does not know anything about state variable defined globally

You have 2 ways to pass the dynamic values to your cell editor.

**Solution 1:**
Get rid of the function in `cellEditorParams` and use it something like this -

```
cellEditorParams: { 
                values: this.state.selectData
        }
```

**Solution 2:**
If you still want to use a function for `cellEditorParams`, you can separate out the function and pass the context using `bind` something like this.

```
  testVals() {
    return {
      values : this.state.selectData
    }
  }
```

And in your colDef -

```
   {
        headerName: "MyListData", 
        field: "item", 
        editable: true, 
        cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor",
        cellEditorParams: this.testVals.bind(this)
    }
```

Example from [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#agselectcelleditor-agpopupselectcelleditor)

Comment: Hi, I hope you had some nice holidays! And thank you very much! I tried Option 1 the first time, but it didn't work, still doesn't work, I get the TypeError, I mentioned in my post. But Option 2 is working!